# Encoding data using For loop to attach xml code in python

Tags: python, list, file, loops, encoding

I need to take a list from File(1) and append xml code to individual items. 
so file(1) will say

```
1
2
3
4
```

And the outcome should say

```
 <jno>1<\jno>
 <hello>2<\hello>
```

How do I use a line from file(1) and than proceed to the next line using new xml codezzzzzzzzzzzzzz/

```
def function(filename):

    file=open(filename)

    FinishFile=open("TigerFitnessXML.txt","w")

    FinishFile.write('<machine>\n')
    FinishFile.write('<supplement>\n')

    for element in file:

        FinishFile.write('<jno>'+ str(element).strip() + '<\jno>\n')
```

Comment: For where are you getting the Tagname (`<jno>, <hello>`) etc?

Comment: these are just made up

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that. Don't forget the open the **outputFile** in append mode, otherwise it will overwrite the previous content in every iteration and you only get the last line.

```
with open('inputfile','r') as f_input,open('outputfile','a') as f_output:
    for line in f_input:
        f_output.write('<tag>'+ line + </tag>)
```

However, you don't know how you get those tags, may be from a list and you will iterate the list with each line of input. But that's the basic frame you need.